# How to get Stored Procedure Executing user MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have Created a stored procedure it automatically adds definer to the creating user that is ok with me but when I try to get the current_user in the stored procedure it give the definer. My requirement is to get the user name who is executing the procedure.

Basic objective of this is:

I have multiple developers sending calls to the database. I want to take revoke their rights from the table and want to provide them a stored procedure with execution rights and then want to track who is updating the data in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can point you to the right direction:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user

From MySQL website related to `USER()` function:

> The value indicates the user name you specified when connecting to the server, and the client host from which you connected.

I had the neede to do something a little different, but in the same realm as you. In my case, I wanted to grant create database to my users without giving them all privileges.

Here's my stored procedure to grant database that I hope you can use as template.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createdb;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
    PROCEDURE createdb (IN dbname CHAR(50))
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1007
    SELECT CONCAT("Can't create database '",
        dbname, "'; database exists") as msg;

    SET @v_createdb = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', dbname);
    SET @v_grant    = CONCAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ', dbname,
        '.* TO \'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1),'\'@\'%\'');

    PREPARE stmt_createdb FROM @v_createdb;
    PREPARE stmt_grant    FROM @v_grant;

    EXECUTE stmt_createdb;
    EXECUTE stmt_grant;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

END $$
```

For complete explanation, you may want to visit http://www.microshell.com/database/how-to-grant-create-database-for-non-root-users/